# How To Change Background Color In a DIV which inside another DIV

Tags: css

I have a page with two menu's on it. The first inside a div is general topics.  The second div is for a specific topic.  I want to change the color of the specific top div to a  different background color.  I just can't seem to make it work.

CSS:

```
#navigation {
  border-top: 2px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#NavigationColorGreen { 
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="navigation" >
  <a href="general-links.htm>General</a>" 
  <hr class="divider" / >
  //* I want to change the background color of this div to green *//
  <div id="NavigationColorGreen" >
    <a href="specific-links.htm">Specifics</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `NavigationColor` to `NavigationColorGreen`

Comment: The selector in your CSS must match the ID in your HTML, but they are different in your code (the id is "NavigationColor" but the id  in your CSS is "NavigationColorGreen"). You should change the CSS rule so it selects the correct ID, (i.e. `#NavigationColor { background-color: green;}` or as @S.Walker says, you could change the id in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you!  

Unfortunately, I attempted to make my example simple and miss typed it...  The second div did actually have the proper id.  The page I am attempting to do is at http://www.lilesnet.com/friends-vacations/2017-06-ireland/index.htm

Comment: I just want the menu items below the horizontal line to be in another color?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is to do with the floating `li`s in your menu. When an element uses `display:float`, it is taken out of the flow of the page. This means that your `NavigationColorGreen` div has no direct content and without anything to give it height, it has height of 0.

To overcome this, you need to use "clearfix". You add this to the containing div (NavigationColorGreen in your case) and it forces it to "clear" the floating elements so that it contains them.

Working example:

```css
#navigation li {
 float: left;
 padding: 1px 8px 1px 8px;
}

#navigation {
border-top: 2px solid #808080;
border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;
background-color: yellow;
}

#navigation ul{
 list-style:none;
 }

#NavigationColorGreen { 
background-color: greenyellow;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* This is for the example only: */
p {font-weight:bold; clear:both; padding:10px 0 0;}
```

```html
<p>Without clearfix</p>
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="general-links.htm">General</a>
    <div id="NavigationColorGreen">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<p>With clearfix</p>
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="general-links.htm">General</a>
    <div id="NavigationColorGreen" class="clearfix">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You sir are a genius!  I would have NEVER in a million years got that!  Getting to be 75 and the ol' head doesn't work like it used to!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Paul

Comment: @PaulLiles Just in case it wasn't clear from the example (because I forgot to mention it specifically) - you just need to add the `clearfix` class into your own CSS, and then just add it to the parent of any floating elements.